# Failed transcript of the JavaScript function to PHP

Tags: javascript, php

How can I transcribe these functions for PHP? I lay in PHP and do not know what functions should be replaced, someone help me?

**JavaScript CODE**

```
function bytesToHex (bytes) {
  bytes = bytes || [];
  var arr = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
    arr.push((bytes[i] < 16 ? '0' : '') + (bytes[i] || 0).toString(16));
  }
  return arr.join('');
}

function bytesFromHex (hexString) {
  var len = hexString.length,
      i,
      start = 0,
      bytes = [];

  if (hexString.length % 2) {
    bytes.push(parseInt(hexString.charAt(0), 16));
    start++;
  }

  for (i = start; i < len; i += 2) {
    bytes.push(parseInt(hexString.substr(i, 2), 16));
  }

  return bytes;
}
```

I tried to do on their own but got no success. See my attempt code:

**PHP CODE:**

```
function bytesToHex ($bytes) {
  $bytes = $bytes || new array();
  $arr = new array();

  for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($bytes); $i++) {
    array_push(($bytes[$i] < 16 ? '0' : '') + ($bytes[$i] || 0).toString(16));
  }
  return arr.join('');
}

function bytesFromHex ($hexString) {
  $len = strlen(hexString);
  $start = 0;
  $bytes = new array();

  if (strlen($hexString) % 2) {
    $bytes = array_push(intval(hexString.charAt(0), 16));
    $start++;
  }

  for ($i = $start; i < $len; $i += 2) {
    $bytes = array_push(intval(hexString.substr($i, 2), 16));
  }

  return bytes;
}
```

Comment: Hexadecimal is just writing numbers in base 16, which conveniently means 2 chars per byte, i.e. `00` is `0 = 0 * 16 + 0`, `FF` is `255 = 15 * 16 + 15`. The alphabet is `0-9A-F`.

Comment: @PaulS. what? Do not know much about PHP, sorry but could guide me better?

Answer (score 2):

> string base_convert ( string $number , int $frombase , int $tobase )

**Example :**

```
echo base_convert('A747', 16, 2);
```

Comment: what? Do not know much about PHP, sorry but could guide me better?